# Android open searchview programmatically

Tags: java, android, kotlin, searchview

I have a search menu:

```
   <item
        android:id="@+id/act_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="Search"/>
```

I need to restore searchview state, when user back to my screen.
So if user left search opened with query - when back menu should be opened.

If after user back to my screen i use `searchView.isIconified = true` - my view is opened, BUT close button disappears if query is empty, and shows up when user type. SO close click, after iconified called, just clears query string, after that close button disappears without possibility to close searchview.
Is there any way to do smth?

`MenuItem.expandActionView()` not working too